# Laravel belongsTo relationship returns null

Tags: laravel, has-many, belongs-to, eloquent-relationship

I'm building a rudimentary CRM app using Laravel 6.0.  Users can freely create accounts, but to get any functionality out of the app, they need to set up a SubscriptionAccount (or join an existing one), which will then allow them to create/manage customer Accounts, add Users, etc. (each is a one to many).

The User model's relationship to SubscriptionAccount model is giving me issues.  For example:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$user->subscription()->create(['name' => 'Test Subscription']);
$user = $user->fresh();
dd($user->subscription); // returns null
```

I suspected it had to do with the `belongsTo` relationship in the User model, but the odd thing is that it actually creates and persists a new SubscriptionAccount while using that relationship (second line above), though if you access `users` relationship from the new SubscriptionAccount it also returns null.

Here are the models:

```php
// User.php
class User
{
    public function subscription()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SubscriptionAccount::class, 'subscription_account_id');
    }
}

// SubscriptionAccount.php
class SubscriptionAccount extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'subscription_account_id');
    }
}
```

The only thing out of the ordinary is shortening the name of the relationship to `subscription` from `SubscriptionAccount`, but that should have been taken care of by specifying the foreign key in both relationships.  Here's the migrations:

```php
Schema::create('subscription_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->uuid('uuid')->unique();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->uuid('uuid')->unique();
    $table->bigInteger('subscription_account_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
    $table->string('name');
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('subscription_account_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('subscription_accounts');
});
```

If I create the user from a SubscriptionAccount (i.e. `$subscriptionAccount->users()->create([...]);` it sets the correct `subscription_account_id` on the `users` table, but doesn't work vice versa.

Comment: whoever downvoted, please let me know how to improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue (feature?) with the `belongsTo` relationship:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29978

To work around it you can associate the models manually:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$sub = Subscription::create(['name' => 'Test Subscription']);
$user->subscription()->associate($sub);
$user->save();
```

Comment: This is the exact issue.  I had been using https://hackernoon.com/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209 as a reference for saving related models "through" existing relationships. Guess I assumed it worked with `create` too.

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method), this method should work. especially given that the example code uses a `belongsTo` relationship.

Comment: Yes, the documentation uses `save()` and `create()` when connecting from parent to child, and uses `associate()` when connecting from child to parent.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using `belongsTo` because a subscription account does not belongs to one user, it can belong to many, you might want to use the `hasOne` relationship instead:

```
public function subscription()
{
    return $this->hasOne(SubscriptionAccount::class, 'id', 'subscription_account_id');
}
```

It will `belongTo` one User if you had a `user_id` within the `subscription_accounts` table.

Let me know if it makes sense and if it works :)

Comment: i agree that a user _can_ only have/belong to one subscription account, but a subscription account can also have multiple users, so inverting the relationship here wouldn't make sense.  I think the relationship type is correct, just don't know why it won't work.

Comment: Have and belong don't  mean the same my friend. Just try my way out, it won't hurt :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I did update the relationship, which resulted in breaking a fifth of my unit tests.  :)

Comment: Smelly tests if they worked with null but not with valid relationship :D

Comment: nearly all the failed tests are the result of 500 server errors.  Laravel's having a tough time dealing with the wrong relationship type.

Comment: 500 is a server error, not an application error. So check your server logs or your IDE if it shows red lines for the file being corrupt.

Comment: actually it's quite a common error i encounter using a tdd workflow with laravel.  e.g. missing a route, missing controller method, missing helper method, etc.  i do appreciate your suggestion and help but unfortunately it didn't fix anything.

Comment: @Erich sorry my friend, I was not giving up as I new I was right. The order of the keys was not set correctly in the method. I edited my answer it should work 100% as I tested it myself with your tables as well :)

Comment: your method could work, if it wasn't **fundamentally the wrong type of relationship**. SubscriptionAccount is the owning model, not User.

Comment: Hm, and I thought that the user owns a subscription account and not vice versa.. Never mind, happy that you found your answer.